# objective-c - how to wait for delegate function before returning from the main function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a hybrid app that calls a function in iOS (*openZipfile()*) to open a .zip file natively.
In the function *openZipfile()* (*objective-c*), the file is selected via *UIDocumentPickerViewController* documentPicker* and then opened and read asynchronously via *didPickDocumentAtURLs*.
I need to wait in *openZipfile()* until the reading of the file is done.
How do I do this? (I'm not versed with objective-c).

Thanks

---

EDIT1:

Thanks for the comments.
I read about *completion handler* and was able to implement the general completion handler pattern similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324095/custom-completion-block-for-my-own-method).

This works ok when I use my own custom function, for example
`-(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock`
But I need to apply the completion handler after the function *didPickDocumentAtURL*.
This function has a specific signature which needs to adhere to the Apple API i.e. I cannot change it from:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
   ...
}
```

to:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url, (myCompletion) compblock
{
    ...
    compblock(YES);
}
```

In my code I trigger the document picker with the following line:

```
[self.VC.navigationController presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I don't fully understand this line: does the parameter `completion:NULL` refer to *completion handler* in any way?
If yes, what is the way to hook it up to the handler?

I also tried to use a semaphore, similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26797096/dont-return-and-wait-the-result-from-other-function-objective-c)
but it doesn't work.

So, how can I call a completion handler **in the context of the predefined function *didPickDocumentAtURL*** ?

Comment: Search for "completion handler" and "callback function"

Comment: `completionBlock` might be also a key word to search along with `async` + `Objective-C`, since it's the type of the parameter (in Swift, it's `closure` for `block`).